# The Enter key do not work for choose the option when in setup in the VM

Tags: centos, networksetup, vmware-fusion

I use VMware Fusion create a CentOS VM, and in the VM, I use `setup` to config the network, but when I enter into this interface, I can not choose the option, I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> there is no response.

And the other question is whats meaning of the netconsole and network here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question You can choose what you want by **space bar** not **enter key.**

Netconsole is a kernel module that sends all kernel messages (output of dmesg command) over the network to another computer. It's not a really console, it's just like remote logging service in your PC.